# Filtering values within a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a dataset of revenue values of table revenues.

I am required to calculate the standard deviation for each day looking at 60 days back prior to current date.
When the standard deviation is calculated, and I run it as follows:

```
SELECT
    [Date],Brand,[Country],[Marketing Channel],
    STDEV(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY Brand, Country,[Marketing Channel] 
        ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) 
    as STD
FROM RevTable
```

The problem is that extreme values within the partition tip the standard deviation up or down. I wish to filter extreme values within the partition itself.

How can I filter out the extreme values in such structure (percentile based filtering is what I had in mind) ?

| Date | Brand | Country | Marketing Channel | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 3,578,834 |
| 1/1/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 90,000 |
| 1/1/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 682,943 |
| 1/2/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 3,731,849 |
| 1/2/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 257 |
| 1/2/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 627,272 |
| 1/3/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,418,136 |
| 1/3/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 40 |
| 1/3/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 479,642 |
| 1/4/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,231,254 |
| 1/4/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ - |
| 1/4/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 635,715 |
| 1/5/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,686,366 |
| 1/5/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 177 |
| 1/5/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 499,026 |
| 1/5/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | $ - |
| 1/6/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,096,472 |
| 1/6/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 465 |
| 1/6/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 653,359 |
| 1/6/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | $ - |
| 1/7/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,962,476 |
| 1/7/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 663 |
| 1/7/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 747,990 |
| 1/8/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 3,092,163 |
| 1/8/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 156 |
| 1/8/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 655,688 |
| 1/8/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | $ - |
| 1/9/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 3,110,117 |
| 1/9/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 153 |
| 1/9/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 571,313 |
| 1/9/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | $ - |
| 1/10/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 3,024,675 |
| 1/10/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 68 |
| 1/10/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 462,699 |
| 1/10/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | $ 563 |
| 1/11/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | $ 2,552,153 |
| 1/11/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | $ 275 |
| 1/11/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | $ 725,954 |

Desired Output:

| Date | Brand | Country | Marketing Channel | STD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | FunGames | Canada | SEO | 522429 |
| 1/1/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | SEO | 97543 |
| 1/2/2021 | FunGames | Canada | Social Networks | 27069 |
| 1/2/2021 | FunGames | Netherlands | Social Networks | 251.66 |

But without outliers within partition

Comment: Given your original query is looking for 60 days of data and your dummy data here doesn't contain anywhere near that, could you please update your sample script and Desired Output to provide values that match your dummy data?  As an example, running the current script on your dummy data doesn't actually return *any* value for the 1st and 2nd of Jan.

Comment: Personally, I would find it useful if you could update your script to only need 3-4 days worth of data and then the dummy data to contain a couple examples of outliers within those few days.  From this you could then provide a Current Output and and a Desired Output.

Comment: Sure. The original dataset is too big so I understand why you receive no data. I will try to cut it shorter

Comment: Whilst the script now references fewer days, I would advise you to actually run it on your exmple data, as it is still returning nonsensical values.  Again, having a *Current* and *Desired* output would also be very helpful

Comment: What is an "extreme value"?

Comment: Extreme values within a group should be determined between two percentiles, let's say 98 and 5 but that relate to the actual partition

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what "extreme values" are.  But you can just use a `CASE` expression.  For instance, if you only wanted values between 10 and 100:

```
SELECT rt.*
       STDEV(CASE WHEN Revenue >= 10 AND Revenue <= 100 THEN Revenue END) OVER
             (PARTITION BY Brand, Country, [Marketing Channel] 
              ORDER BY [Date]
              ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING
             ) as STD
FROM RevTable rt ;
```

`STDEV()` -- as with most aggregation and window functions -- ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to identify the extreme values by  the values over certain percentiles inside the partition. Let's say between the 98th percentile and the 5th percentile.